# android how to get the name of connected bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth

i want to know how to get the name of the connected bluetooth device in android 
here is the code

```
NetworkInfo bluetooth = connectivityManager .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_BLUETOOTH);
if(bluetooth.isConnected())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(myprofile3Context,"bluetooth is connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

here i check if bluetooth device is connected or not. if bluetooth is connected  i want know how to get the name of connected device.

Comment: this will help you https://cmanios.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/bluetooth-adapter-device-name-and-mac-address-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```java
public String getLocalBluetoothName(){
    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null){
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    }
    String name = mBluetoothAdapter.getName();
    if(name == null){
        System.out.println("Name is null!");
        name = mBluetoothAdapter.getAddress();
    }
    return name;
}
```

Comment: i can not get the own device name. i want to get the other connected device name

Comment: @faisaliqbal , for me also getting same , Have you got solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                          //you can get name by device.getName()

        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACL_DISCONNECTED
                .equals(action)) {

        }
    }
 };
```

Use `extends` `BroadcastReceiver` and add `permissions` in `manifest`

Comment: i want it without broadcast reciver